# Converting bottle threads from diagram to a 3D model

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing, mathematics, screw-modifier

## Goal:

I'm trying to model the threads of a polar springs 500ml bottle in Blender 2.8x so I can 3D print an adapter for it.

[image: Thread Image]

## Issue:

I'm having issues converting what Blender 2.8x calls **Screw** and what the diagram calls **Helix Angle** and **Travel Per Turn**.

[image: Screw Mod]

## Full diagram of threads I'm following

I've been able to find some good dimensions for the threads to start with.
Link to full diagram below.
https://www.bevtech.org/assets/Threadspecs/2072573_tmp.pdf

## Tried:

I was thinking of using the profile of a 3 edge plane
See image below

[image: 3 edge plane]

And using the screw modifier to make each of the 3 threads (each of the 3 threads only go around 73-75% of the bottle head) see image below (I was doing it this way to have more control over each thread since 3D printing this may require fine tuning each thread)

[image: 3 turns]

To test the treads I would just use a cap that comes with the 500ml Poland springs water bottle.

Ps: I was following parts of this tutorial
https://youtu.be/kVNxfCtoG_A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a nice diagram almost calls for the *Simple Deform Modifier* :)

1. Model the thread as in the diagram
2. Add a Simple Deform Modifier > Bend
3. Choose an axis and set angle to 360°

[image]

Comment: Wow! How / what technique did you use to model that?

Comment: It's just a subdivided plane with projected threads. I'll describe the process in detail if you ask it as a new question :).

Comment: Thanks, I just made another question.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/190092/creating-a-subdivided-plane-using-projected-threads

Comment: what technique did you use to extrude the threads?

Comment: Hello :). Blender has an Extrude Tool for this. First, I extruded all faces to give the plane thickness, then I extruded only the threads.