# Creating a subdivided plane using projected threads

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, 3d-printing

How can I create a subdivided plane using projected threads.
*(Part 02 of [Converting bottle threads from diagram to 3D model](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/190059/78972))*

I'm trying to model the threads of a polar springs 500ml bottle in Blender 2.8x so I can 3D print an adapter for it.

[image: Treads]

I've been able to find some good dimensions for the threads to start with. Link to full diagram below. https://www.bevtech.org/assets/Threadspecs/2072573_tmp.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using a subdivided plane and the *Knife Project* function.

1. Make a plane of required length and subdivide it
2. Create your threads (I used another plane) and move it in front
3. Select Threads + Plane and go Edit Mode > Mesh > Knife Project

Making thread pattern ,<kbd>Shift+D</kbd> to duplicate the vertices

[image]

Projecting threads onto the subdivided plane.

[image]