# Mining Blade thoughts?

Tags: modeling, topology

I have this mining machine to model and before I launch into the blade, just wondering if you have any advice on how I could easily model the blades, notice the red lines that show the curvature of them. And also the blade tube can detatch like with the green lines I have shown, any easy way to cut that out?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The curved blades you could model like bottle threads? Have a look here: [Converting bottle threads from diagram...](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/190059/107598) and here: [How to model the bottle threads?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50102/107598), Or use other hard surface modeling techniques. E.g. add a cylinder, then add plane (rotated, subdivided a few times, placed in the cylinder), add a *Shrinkwrap* modifier (mode Project) + a *Solidify* modifier to the plane to create a blade

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay, but spikeyxxx on the CGCookie forums had a good idea, ie use the Worm Gear (Shift A > Mesh > Gears > Worm) as a base and create it from that.